# I am trying to insert into sql but it keep giving me errors

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to insert to sql through java but it gives me errors

```
public void addStudent(String name, int SID, String gender, String major, String nationality, int mobileNo,
            String birthDate, int deptNo) {

        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into students values("+ SID+ ", '"+name+"','"
                    + gender+"',"+mobileNo + ",TO_Date('"+birthDate+"', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '"+ major+"', '"+nationality+"', null, "+deptNo+");");
            stmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }
    }
```

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended

Comment: first of all put the resulting query into a `String`  and print it (in the catch block) so you can check it. Second better use `PreparedStatement` **with** placeholders and use corrresponding `set*` methods to set the values. Third some drivers don't accept the semicolon at the end of the statement (mostly oracle about version 9, no idea what the actual ones do)

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise you to use `PreparedStatement` like that.
This is what i would have done :

```
public void addStudent(Student student){
      int SID = student.getSID();
      String name = student.getName();
      // etc ...

      String query = "INSERT INTO students VALUES(?,?)";

      try{

         PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(query);
         prep.setInt(1,SID);
         prep.setString(2,name);
         // etc ...

         prep.executeUpdate();

      }catch (SQLException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PreparedStatement`like below:

```
       try {
         //passing placeholder 
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into students values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
          //giving valuesto each placeholder 
           stmt.setInt(1,SID);
            stmt.setString(2,name);
            stmt.setString(3,gender);
            stmt.setInt(4,mobileNo );
            stmt.setDate(5,birthDate);
            stmt.setString(6,major);
            stmt.setString(7,nationality);
            stmt.setString(8,null);
            stmt.setInt(9,deptNo ); 
            //executing update,insert value in table
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }
```